# Drupal 7 LDAP Authorization does not map ldap groups to drupal roles

Tags: drupal, ldap, authorization, roles, usergroups

In our company we've recently migrated from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 and I'm having troubles configuring the LDAP. Authentication is working ok, but the ldap groups aren't created as drupal roles.

With Drupal 6 and LDAP Integration the configuration was easy:
Check "Groups exist as LDAP entries where a multivalued attribute contains the members' CNs" + set groups DN to "ou=Groups,dc=domini,dc=intranet" and "Attribute holding group members:" to "memberUid".

Width Drupal 7 I've activated the modules "LDAP Authorization" and "LDAP Authorization - Drupal Roles" (Configuration here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/171128/Configuration.txt). I've activated the debug log, I attach the syslog and watchdog logs for a successful login: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/171128/logSyslog.txt + http://dl.dropbox.com/u/171128/logWatchdog.txt.

The strange thing is that I can view in the logs that Drupal is searching in the "ou=Groups,dc=domini,dc=intranet" search base and the filter "(&(objectClass=posixgroup)(memberuid=12345678Z))". And that's ok! I try that in Apache Directory and the search returns the user groups.

Can anybody help me? Is this a bug?

Comment: For future reference, this has been discussed on the drupal site forums at https://www.drupal.org/node/1917254